# VueJS Component DOM not updating after AJAX Promise

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, promise, vue.js

I'm aware of the common problems updating data in a Vue application after an AJAX callback - I've read through the [common gotchas](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/) and fixed similar problems using `Vue.set` in the past, but it's not working for me today.

The only difference I can think of is I'm calling a service inside a component (`.vue` file)

If I inspect the dom with the VueJS tools in chrome I can see the data from the service being assigned to my `module.options` property, which is all happening in the created function but it's not drawing it on screen

Attached is the full `.vue` component and a screen shot showing the data logged in the dev tools and the template not rendering it.

The snippet wont run, just a nicer format than pasting it directly into the post.

In short, the response from `this.build_service.getOptionsForModule` is giving me what I want and `Vue.set( this.module, 'options', res.options )` seems to work but doesn't update the DOM.

Any ideas why?

```js
<template>
 <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" :href="'#collapse' + module.field" :data-parent="'#' + group_name" >
                    {{module.title}}
                    <!-- <span class="pull-right" v-if="module.options.length"> -->
                        [{{module.options.length}}]
                    <!-- </span> -->
                </a>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div :id="'collapse' + module.field" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{module}}
                    
                    <!-- v-model="modules.selected[ module.field ]" -->

                    <select id="" data-target="#" class="form-control" :disabled="!module.is_active">
                        <option :value="{}">Select {{module.title}}...</option>
                        <option v-for="option in module.options" :value="option" v-html="option.name">
                        </option>
                    </select>
                    
                    <!-- @change="modules.checkChildren( module )" -->
                    
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-success mediumButton" @click="create( module )">
                        Create
                    </button>
                    
                    <!-- :disabled="!modules.isSelected( module.field )" -->

                    <button class="btn btn-primary mediumButton" @click="edit( module )">
                        Edit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>


<script>

    import { EventBus } from '../event-bus.js';
    var BuildService = require('../services/build-service');

    export default {
        name: 'module',
        props: [ 'group_name', 'module' ],
        data: function() {
            return {
             
            }
        },
        created: function() {
            console.log('single module component created');

            this.build_service = new BuildService();

            console.log( this.module );

            // if there are no options, load from service
            if( !this.module.options.length && this.module.parent === '' ) {

                this.build_service.getOptionsForModule( this.module )
                    .then(( res ) => {

                        if( res.length ) {
                            res = res[ 0 ];

                            Vue.delete( 
                                this.module,
                                'options'
                            );

                            Vue.set( 
                                this.module,
                                'options', 
                                res.options
                            );

                        } else {
                            console.error('no options found');
                            // TODO: status alert
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(function(err){
                        console.error(err);
                    });
            }
        },
        methods: {
            create: function( module ) {
                console.log('creating record for', module);
            },
            edit: function( module ) {
                console.log('editing', module);
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

[image: vuejs app and dev tools inspection]

Comment: It's one of the `props`, although I was just thinking does that mean I can't change it

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaah, think I've found it in the docs: `Define a local data property that uses the prop’s initial value as its initial value:`https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Comment: add an answer for future users :)

Comment: I totally will once I've tested it and confirmed it works first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often the case that I answer my own questions within minutes of posting, but might be useful for others in the future.

I was trying to modify a prop that was passed down from a parent component and you can't do that from the child (well not without sending events up high to change it so the data can flow down)

I needed to make a copy of the prop into the data structure (someone did comment that I hadn't registered the module in the data structure, so they were right about that)

I found a clear solution in the docs (RTFM!!)

> One-Way Data Flow
>
> All props form a one-way-down binding between the child property and the parent one
>
> ...
>
> There are usually two cases where it’s tempting to mutate a prop:
> 1.The prop is used to only pass in an initial value, the child component simply wants to use it as a local data property afterwards;

...

> The proper answer to these use cases are:
>
> Define a local data property that uses the prop’s initial value as its initial value:

```
props: ['initialCounter'],
data: function () {
    return { counter: this.initialCounter }
}
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Comment: can't accept own answer for 2 days but I will do, thanks